# lodash - sum of two objects by key

Tags: lodash

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488048/javascript-sum-of-two-object-with-same-properties) question asked previously, is there an easy way to sum two objects, or an array of objects, by key in Lodash?

```
{ a:12, b:8, c:17 }
```

and

```
{ a:2, b:3, c:1 }
```

should give

```
{ a:14, b:11, c:18 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#mergeWith):

```js
var o1 = { a:12, b:8, c:17 };
var o2 = { a:2, b:3, c:1 };

var result = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, function(objValue, srcValue) {
  return _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : srcValue; 
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you know that all values are numbers, or you always want to add values together, you can use [`_.add()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#add) as the merging customizer:

```js
var o1 = { a:12, b:8, c:17, d: 'a' };
var o2 = { a:2, b:3, c:1, d: 'b' };

var result = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, _.add);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

To merge an array of objects use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with `_.mergeWith()`:

```js
var arr = [{ a:12, b:8, c:17 }, { a:2, b:3, c:1 }];

var result = _.mergeWith({}, ...arr, function(objValue, srcValue) {
  return _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : srcValue; 
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var arr = [{ a:12, b:8, c:17 }, { a:2, b:3, c:1 }];

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
  return  _.mergeWith(r, o, function(objValue, srcValue) {
    return _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : srcValue; 
  });
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was trying to use reduce instead of spread, thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome. I've added an example with reduce instead of spread.

Comment: In the first example, couldn't you use `_.add` as the iteratee?  `_.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, _.add)` -- this is concise and to-the-point.  I think the `_.isNumber()` check is redundant; `_.add` is going to type-check anyway and works fine if either argument is `undefined`.

Comment: You can use `_.add()` (I've add another example with it). However, use carefully because `_.add()` tries to sum everything, and it might cause weird results (the letter 'a' + null -> 'anull').

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use **assignWith** and **add**

```js
var o1 = { a:12, b:8, c:17 };
var o2 = { a:2, b:3, c:1 };

const combined = _.assignWith({}, o1, o2, _.add)

console.log(combined);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```