# How to get an union list like in sql?

Tags: javascript

I need to do an union on an array like the UNION sql statement.

my original array :

```
const prices = [
{name:'product_name1', price_a:1.0, price_b:null, price_c:null},
{name:'product_name1', price_a:null, price_b:2.0, price_c:3.0},
{name:'product_name2', price_a:2.0, price_b:null, price_c:null},
{name:'product_name2', price_a:null, price_b:null, price_c:1.0},
]
```

my wanted array :

```
const prices = [
{name:'product_name1', price_a:1.0, price_b:2.0, price_c:3.0},
{name:'product_name2', price_a:2.0, price_b:null, price_c:1.0},
]
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: What if there are conflicting non-null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array and look for same name object and update the prices properties.

```js
const
    prices = [{ name: 'product_name1', price_a: 1.0, price_b: null, price_c: null }, { name: 'product_name1', price_a: null, price_b: 2.0, price_c: 3.0 }, { name: 'product_name2', price_a: 2.0, price_b: null, price_c: null }, { name: 'product_name2', price_a: null, price_b: null, price_c: 1.0 }],
    result = prices.reduce((r, { name, ...prices }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.name === name);
        if (temp) {
            Object.entries(prices).forEach(([k, v]) => v === null || (temp[k] = v));
        } else {
            r.push(temp = { name, ...prices });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would basically need to merge elements with the same key based on some logic.
the simplest case is if you need to overwrite the values. Then you would use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). 
Yet if you need to apply **different logic**, say summation, then you'll have to write it using array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods. 
Check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194211/react-native-js-sorting-two-list-and-increment-number-for-the-same-id) for many different ways to do that
Cheers!